# Python PIP on Ubuntu 18.04 Update

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and have already installed pip3

```
~$ pip3 --version
```

> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

My question is should I update pip to the latest version, or not?

Comment: Yes you should!

Comment: From my point of view, **no you shouldn't**. Instead you should use virtual environments and update _pip_ in these virtual environments (if necessary, it can also work fine with the original version). I would recommend to never ever use the global _pip_ from the operating system, for example I never install it, to prevent myself from using it by mistake.